# holdout function for rpart() in R not found

Tags: r

Very simple code below:

```
H=holdout(1:10,ratio=2,internal=TRUE,mode="order")
print(H)
```

But the error I get is:

```
could not find function "holdout"
```

What library, or what should I do to get holdout working for my rpart analysis?

Answer (score 0):

`rminer` has a holdout function. `DMwR` has a function `holdOut`. I suggest searching on Google, for example, 'R holdout function' to find the answer you're looking for.